# Optimising circular motion for high downforce vehicles

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, centripetal-force

I'm doing a school assessment where i am trying to optimise the entry speed into a corner for an F1 car. With this there are a few assumptions for the sake of simplicity.

1. entry speed = exit speed, as in $u=v$ and there is no drag acting on the vehicle
2. the smallest turning circle of the car is 9m, i.e min-radius > 9m
3. maximum velocity is =97m/s
   To get uniform circular motion Ive equated $Fc=Ff$, to get as follows:

$\frac{mv^2}{r}=\mu(mg+F_z)$. here m=800kg, u=1.6, g=9.81, $F_z=19.9v^2$ ---> $F_z=\frac{C_L\rho v^2 A}{2}$, where $C_L$=2.5, $\rho$=1.225, A=13, as such $F_z=19.9v^2$

equating this for the radius of the curve travelled per velocity I get;
$r=\frac{mv^2}{\mu(mg+19.9v^2)}$

to then get the arc length for distance travelled i am using radians of each specific turn in a track i am wishing to optimise for $r\theta=l$. Thus $l=\frac{\theta mv^2}{\mu(mg+19.9v^2)}$

then to relate it to time I've used $v=\frac{l}{t}$, for l=vt. which gets me $t=\frac{\theta mv}{\mu(mg+19.9v^2)}$

[image]

this is the graph i get which isn't giving me the expected relationship at all. Firstly, i was hoping to see a minima for t(x) to see a minimum time and thus be able to optimise the equation, instead I'm getting a maxima that is the opposite of the purpose of the optimisation.

Secondly, I'm confused as to why t(x) isn't the same as l'(x) as the gradient of distance over speed should be equal to time no?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, again it is just a school project and I understand I have assumed some pretty major variables such as drag to be negligent but I've even tried inputting that and it still doesn't give the relationship i'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The equation that you have, $mv^2/r = \mu(m g + F_z)$, is only true if the force of static friction is at its maximum value, ie the car is about to start skidding.  More generally, what you have is $mv^2/r = F_{fr}$ and $F_{fr}\leq\mu(m g + F_z)$. This inequality is what would place the bound on the maximum speed at which the vehicle could traverse the curve.

Comment: I'm assuming the car is operating right on the limit of grip as racecars and their drivers often do push the car to the very limit. I'm trying to minimise the time cost but with my current formulas there isn't a minima, i'm wondering if Ive forgotten a variable or something that would fix it?

Comment: Maybe I've misunderstood something here.  But for a given speed, wouldn't you either travel at the fastest speed that avoids skidding or at the maximum speed of your vehicle, whichever one is lower?

Comment: basically I don't understand why l(x) appraoches infinity on the x-axis, as this suggests that the fast you go there is proportionately less distance to travel. I understand how this makes sense with the equation I am using but I am wondering what I am missing as I expected it to extend to infinity on the y-axis as that is what happens in reality - this also happens once you remove the Fz part of the equation as it ust becomes a parabola